# Need to create this graph in Highcharts

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

[Graph with two series label](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ilPEz.png)

The main challenge I'm facing is placing two series labels.
The graph is constructed based on the values within brackets (Eg. (10.3)).
But I need to show another value on top each columns.
how can I achieve this.

P.S: I can't alter the design.

Comment: Can you provide some code example of your issue? At least you can edit data of the chart with jQuery after chart is builded.

Comment: Use renderer to add custom text.  http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#Renderer.text

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add your another value array as a series ,make it visible false either on chart load or via visible:false in series array. Then use stacklabel and get this extra series's values  using formatter function, So it won't should you series total but instead desired value.

```
  stackLabels: { 
                enabled: true,
                formatter: function() {                       
                    return (this.axis.series[1].yData[this.x] ) ;

                }
            }
```

[See working Demo here](https://jsfiddle.net/Nishith/r6ymnL1j/16/)